# Both row from one table in a drop down - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel 5.2 and Laravel Collective here. So I have this problem - I'm trying to make a drop down (select) with the `first_name` and the `last_name` of my user but in my User table `first_name` and `last_name` are in different rows. How can i display them both together in one drop down?

Here what i Have in the controller:

`'teachers'=>User::where('type','=','teacher')->lists('first_name', 'last_name','id'),`

With this I only see `first_name`.

And  in the view:

`{!! Form::select('teacher_name', $teachers, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

The table structure:

`Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('first_name', 20);
            $table->string('last_name', 20);
            $table->integer('class_id')
                ->unsigned()
                ->nullable();
            $table->enum('type', ['admin', 'teacher', 'student']);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();`

Someone?

Comment: What do you mean by first_name and last_name are in different rows? Could you post your table structure here?

Comment: wait I will update :)

Comment: Okay you see only the first_name because it is working as it should. When you are passing the $teachers array in {!!Form::select()!!}, it will populate it as key value pair for the select options. So if you inspect the select element with devtools you will be able to see the last_name as value for each options. For Eg: <select><option value="last_name">first_name</option></select>If you want to display first_name<space>last_name and want the value to be the user's id then you will have to build the teachers array in the controller accordingly

Comment: And how can I build this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes come in handy when doing things like this. In your teacher's model, you could put:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

Then in your controller put:

```
$teachers = Teacher::lists('full_name','id');
```

..and your view will now work as it is.

Comment: Just my in my controller should be `'teachers'=>User::where('type','=','teacher')->get()->lists('full_name'),`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
$teachers = User::where('type', 'teacher')->get();
$teachersArray = [];
foreach ($teachers as $teacher){
    $teachersArray[$teacher->id] = $teacher->first_name.' '.$teacher->last_name;
}
```

Passing the $teachersArray to your view and in your form :

```
{!! Form::select('teacher_name', $teachersArray, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: You may need to initialize the $teachersArray outside of the for loop